# Is it haram to marry zoroastrians?

Tags: nikah

I heard that zoroastrians were called Majus in Quran, and people that practiced shirk religions were called Mushrikeen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is impermissible to marry them, and it was also impermissible for Muslim men to have intercourse with Zoroastrian slave-girls until they accepted Islām.

Comment: وأما قوله ولا يحل وطء أمة مجوسية بملك اليمين فهذا أيضا قول جمهور أهل العلم
ولم يختلف فيه فقهاء أهل الأمصار من أهل الرأي والآثار ~ [Istidhkaar Ibn 'Abd al-Barr](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1722/2373)

Comment: @UmH is correct, Imām Abū Hanīfah and his madh'hab did not consider it permissible.